# Stop numbers going into Scientific notation

Tags: c++, scientific-notation

I have doubles that are very big and keep going into Scientific notation (e.g. 3.12002769e+27) when outputted. How can I stop this as I'm writing to a file and can't have this.

Comment: Use the std::fixed manipulator http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed